# decodeURIComponent throwing an error 'URI malformed'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, urldecode

As `unescape` has been  deprecated I have chosen `decodeURIComponent` , but it doesn't work as expected . `decodeURIComponent`  cant decode the following URI component

```
Coast%20Guard%20Academy%20to%20hold%20annual%20Women%92s%20%91Leadhership%92%20event
```

While decoding the above string decodeURIComponent throws an error, which blocks the remaining javascript execution.

Is there is any solution to fix this ?

Comment: please post the error

Comment: @roryok — "URI malformed"

Comment: i am getting `URIError: URI malformed` , try this in console `decodeURIComponent('Coast%20Guard%20Academy%20to%20hold%20annual%20Women%92s%20%91Leadhership%92%20event')`

Comment: The issue is with the `%91` and `%92` characters - the quotes. I'm not sure on exactly why this is

Comment: Consider this solution:https://stackoverflow.com/a/45732650/4572425

Answer (score 3):

The `%91` and `%92` characters were encoded using an ANSI codepage. `decodeURIComponent()` [expects the string to have been encoded as UTF-8](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.3.2):

> The `decodeURIComponent` function computes a new version of a URI in which each escape sequence and UTF-8 encoding of the sort that might be introduced by the `encodeURIComponent` function is replaced with the character that it represents.

The two quotes should be encoded as `%E2%80%98` and `%E2%80%99`.