# decodeURIComponent throwing an error "URIError: URI malformed at decodeURIComponent" as it is not able to decode rawurlencode(data) from the php

Tags: javascript, php, url-encoding, decodeuricomponent

`decodeURIComponent` throwing an error while decoding the encoded data in php.

data is `encoded` in `PHP` using `rawurlencode` function and while `decoding` in `js` we are using `decodeURIComponent`.

For few data I am getting an error for other values it is working fine.

**Question:**
I want to know is there any alternate to `rawurlencode` or `decodeURIComponent`

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow sunil :). it will be easy for the ppl who can give your answer if you provide your code or anything which you tried so far & if any error or something you got than please provide error log ,exception etc. so user can easily go to that direction and provide you help

Comment: Thanks user1140237 :)
Sorry user1140237 as I cant provide any logs as I work for a company but my question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28063750/decodeuricomponent-throwing-an-error-uri-malformed but it is not helping me in any way

Comment: I found the reason why it was happening
**Process:**
Fetch the data from db ----> encode the data in php using rawurlencode() ----> Send the data to frontend ----> Decode the data using decodeURIComponent(),process it and display it.

**Problem:**
Db has special character �(http://www.cogsci.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=%F6&mode=char) which was not encoded properly so decodeURIComponent function was throwing error.