# Converting a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I convert a string

```
This:
file:///C://Program%20Files//Microsoft%20Office//OFFICE11//EXCEL.EXE 

To this:
C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\OFFICE11\\EXCEL.EXE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would do the trick:

```
function getPath(url) {
  return  decodeURIComponent(url).replace("file:///","").replace(/\//g,"\\");
}
```

[You can try it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/qvEYP/).

Answer (score 2):

Unescape, replace `file:///` and replace `//`.

```
// if you face problems with IE use `unescape` instead.
var d = decodeURIComponent("file:///C://Program%20Files//Microsoft%20Office//OFFICE11//EXCEL.EXE")
d = d.replace(/file:\/\/\//i, "").replace(/\/\//g, "\\\\");
```

Returns

```
"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\OFFICE11\\EXCEL.EXE"
```

For a single backslash use

```
d = d.replace(/file:\/\/\//i, "").replace(/\/\//g, "\\");
```

Which results in

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\EXCEL.EXE"
```

Comment: You'd want to use `decodeURIComponent()` here instead of `unescape()`.  They're not the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619323/decodeuricomponent-vs-unescape-what-is-wrong-with-unescape

Answer (score 0):

This solution avoids unnecessary replaces:

```
var input = "file:///C://Program%20Files//Microsoft%20Office//OFFICE11//EXCEL.EXE";

// Remove file:///
if (input.length > 8 && input.substr(0, 8) == "file:///")
  input = input.substr(8);

input = decodeURIComponent(input).replace(/\/\//g, "\\\\"));
```

Comment: This would only replace the *first* `//` occurrence, JavaScript's a bit wacky like that, you need the global option to make it replace *all* occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

Use `decodeURIComponent` to fix the `%20` and similar url escaped chars. Then simply substring out the pathname (after string position 8) and replace the `//` with `\\` using split / join.

or...

```
var original = "file:///C://Program%20Files//Microsoft%20Office//OFFICE11//EXCEL.EXE ";

var fixed = decodeURIComponent(original.substr(8)).split('//').join('\\');
```

You could use replace instead of the split / join.

Comment: See this question for reasons not to use `unescape()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619323/decodeuricomponent-vs-unescape-what-is-wrong-with-unescape