# JavaScript-friendly binary-safe data format design (not JSON or XML)

Tags: javascript, c, serialization, data-formats

*First and foremost: JSON and XML are not an option in this specific case, please don't suggest them. If this makes it easier to accept that fact, imagine that I intend to reinvent the wheel for self-education.*

*Back to the point:*

I need to design a binary-safe data format to encode some datagrams I send to a particular dumb server that I write (in C if that matters).

To simplify the question, let's say that I'm sending only numbers, strings and arrays.

Important fact: Server does not (and should not) know anything about Unicode and stuff. It treats all strings as binary blobs (and never looks inside them).

The format that I originally devised is as follows:

- Datagram: `<Number:size>\n<Value1>...<ValueN>`
- Value:

  - Number: `N\n<Value>\n`
  - String: `S\n<Number:size-in-bytes>\n<bytes>\n`
  - Array: `A\n<Number:size>\n<Value0>...<ValueN>`

Example:

```
[ 1, "foo", [] ]
```

Serializes as follows:

```
1   ; number of items in datagram
A   ; -- array --
3   ; number of items in array
N   ; -- number --
1   ; number value
S   ; -- string --
3   ; string size in bytes
foo ; string bytes
A   ; -- array --
0   ; number of items in array
```

The problem is that I [can not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515869/string-length-in-bytes-in-javascript) reliably get a string size in bytes in JavaScript.

So, the question is: how to change the format, so a string can be both saved in JS and loaded in C neatly.

I do not want to add Unicode support to the server.

And I do not quite want to decode strings on server (say, from base64 or simply to unescape \xNN sequences) — this would require work with dynamic string buffers, which, given how dumb the server is, is not so desirable...

Any clues?

Comment: @Diodeus: thanks, I've got a feeling that I'll need it :-)

Comment: Have you looked at JSON?  (Just kidding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that reading UTF-8 in plain C is [not that scary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517205/how-to-read-utf-8-string-given-its-length-in-characters-in-plain-c89) after all. So I'm extending the protocol to handle UTF-8 strings natively. (But will appreciate an answer to this question as it stands.)

Comment: Actually it **is** a bit scary. But it seems that I managed. :-)