# How to get the string length in bytes in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to get the string length in bytes in nodejs? If I have a string, like this: `äáöü` then str.length will return with 4. But how to get that, how many bytes form the string?

Comment: A string does not *have* a length in bytes. This depends on the encoding used.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
str = 'äáöü';

console.log(str + ": " + str.length + " characters, " +
  Buffer.byteLength(str, 'utf8') + " bytes");

// äáöü: 4 characters, 8 bytes
```

[Buffer.byteLength(string, [encoding])](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#static-method-bufferbytelengthstring-encoding)

Comment: Is there a way to automatically get KB, MB, as appropriate etc (human readable size)

Comment: chovy, `npm install filesize`

Answer (score 11):

```
function getBytes(string){
  return Buffer.byteLength(string, 'utf8')
}
```

Comment: This is just a copy of the accepted answer, put into a function.

Comment: Buffer.byteLength is already a such function, and example above at least shows it's usage. With the same luck you could do `var byteLength = Buffer.byteLength` and it would also work just the same.

Comment: The simplest and best answer

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use [`TextEncoder`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_class_util_textencoder)

```
new TextEncoder().encode(str).length
```

Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515869/string-length-in-bytes-in-javascript/34332105)

Assume it's slower though

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(Buffer.from('example..').length)
```

Answer (score 1):

This depends where the string is.

In JavaScript engines (at least, in most of them, including V8, used by Node.js and Chromium/Chrome), strings [are encoded as UTF-16 internally](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Code_unit). In UTF-16 encoding, every character is either 2 or 4 bytes long. Every character that's common in any major human language  (and many that aren't) are encoded in 2 bytes (one code unit), while characters from rarer languages, emoji, and unusual symbols are often encoded in 4 bytes (two code units).

Moreover, the JavaScript string `length` property actually does not return the number of characters in the string, it returns the number of code units. For example, `''.length` returns 2 even though the string contains only one *character*.

Finally, the strings are almost certainly (though I have not checked) null-terminated, so throw on an extra 2 bytes for that.

Putting it together, the length of a string residing in your Node.js script's memory is `(str.length * 2) + 2` bytes.

On the other hand, when you send a string in an HTTP request, or write it to a file, it will typically be converted by default to UTF-8 before being transmitted to its destination. Characters in UTF-8 can be 1, 2, 3, or 4 bytes long (not counting the phenomenon of "over-long characters" and potential future expansion).

For this, I have nothing to add on top of the other answers to this question, which show how to calculate the length of a string in UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specific encoded, here is `iconv` example

```
  var iconv = require('iconv-lite');
  var buf =iconv.encode('äáöü', 'utf8');
  console.log(buf.length);
  // output: 8
```