# Node.js buffer with é character

Tags: node.js

I've created a simple buffer, and I've put into it my string `"Héllo"`

Here's my code:

```
var str = "Héllo";
var buff = new Buffer(str.length);
buff.write(str);

console.log(buff.toString("utf8"));
```

however, it returns `"Héll"` and not `Héllo`, why?

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF-8 characters can have different length - from 1 byte to 4 bytes - look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9533324/4486609

So, it is not ok to assume that it have 2 bytes, as you did.

As for the right length, look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9864762/4486609

Comment: so how could I get the length with the utf8 characters?

Comment: yep but I've also said "How can I fix that?"

Comment: Thanks, add it in your answer so I can set it as valid :p

Answer (score 1):

`.length` is reporting the number of chars, not the number of bytes. But `new Buffer()` is expecting the number of bytes. The 'é' requires two bytes. So the last char is falling off the end of the buffer and being truncated.

If you don't need to support anything older than Node.js 4.x.x, you can use `Buffer.from()`:

```
let buffer = Buffer.from('Héllo');
console.log(buffer.toString()); // 'Héllo'
```

Comment: and if my string is dynamic?

Comment: Might be my ignorance, but I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "dynamic".  You can pass a variable in like `Buffer.from(myString)` if that will suffice.

Comment: ah sorry i didn't see your edit, and how can I do the same with new Buffer(int) ? I need this method because I've to add other things after, and I want to add them to the length