# How to calculate Content-Length in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

```
function LikesDislikes () {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/keDZXXDxK1c/ratings',
        type:"POST",
        data: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
                   xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
                <yt:rating value="like"/>
            </entry>',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type":"application/atom+xml",
            "Content-Length":,
            "Authorization":"Bearer ya29.AHES6ZQ59RrQgujZmIjssBdYlwwLVrpCodnirdLROi7-g7U",
            "X-GData-Key":"key=AIzaSyAPrtP2Tq4m5WVInCvCWptVAKPhQ4SQNZA",
            "GData-Version":"2"
        },
        // Content-Type:"application/atom+xml",
        error: function() { alert("No data found."); },
        // contentType: "text/xml",
        success: function (response) {
            alert('response:' + response);
        }
   });

}
```

How can I calculate the `Content-Length` in the above code?

Answer (score 9):

As said in [specs](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13)

> The Content-Length entity-header field indicates the size of the
>   entity-body, in decimal number of OCTETs

Please look as this question [String length in bytes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515869/string-length-in-bytes-in-javascript).

Basically if your data contains only ASCII characters everything should be quite easy

```
function LikesDislikes () {

    var data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
           xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
        <yt:rating value="like"/>
    </entry>';

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/keDZXXDxK1c/ratings',
        type:"POST",
        data: data,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type":"application/atom+xml",
            "Content-Length": data.length,
            "Authorization":"Bearer ya29.AHES6ZQ59RrQgujZmIjssBdYlwwLVrpCodnirdLROi7-g7U",
            "X-GData-Key":"key=AIzaSyAPrtP2Tq4m5WVInCvCWptVAKPhQ4SQNZA",
            "GData-Version":"2"
        },
        // Content-Type:"application/atom+xml",
        error: function() { alert("No data found."); },
        // contentType: "text/xml",
        success: function (response) {
            alert('response:' + response);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The string .length property has problems with byte length, you should probably adjust your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72677560/what-can-cause-string-length-to-be-incorrectly-reported-in-node-javascript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515869/string-length-in-bytes-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

The **Content-Length** entity header is indicating the size of the entity-body, in bytes, sent to the recipient.

### Syntax

```
Content-Length: <length>
```

### Directives

```
<length>
The length in decimal number of octets.
```

### Content-Length Calculation

- If the request body is a String you can simple use the length of the body.
- If the request body is a JSON you can just stringify the body.

```
const requestBody =
{
  data: 
  {
     ...
  }
};
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", JSON.stringify(requestBody).length.toString());
```

Read more at:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Length

Comment: The string .length property has problems with byte length, you should probably adjust your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72677560/what-can-cause-string-length-to-be-incorrectly-reported-in-node-javascript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515869/string-length-in-bytes-in-javascript