# How to calculate length of object being sent in POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've an object like

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "Value": 10,
    "UId" : "ab400"
}
```

How can I calculate the length of this so that I'm able to send it in ajax request.

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/keDZXXDxK1c/ratings',
    type:"POST",
    data: data,
    headers: {
        "Content-Type":"application/atom+xml",
        "Content-Length": data.length,
```

I tried using stringfying the JSON but the length comes incorrect 
Tried : JSON.stringify(data).length

Comment: what do you mean, incorrect?

Comment: what do you mean by "length" of an object? the amount of key/value pairs? please be more precise. JSON.stringify(data).length will give you the amount of characters in you object string

Comment: Why are you putting `JSON.stringify` anywhere near `application/atom+xml`?!

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762778/how-to-calculate-content-length-in-javascript

Comment: If you look in the Network Inspector you will see the content length header is added automatically.

Comment: What you're doing makes no sense; jQuery sends the object using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, you're determining the length using the JSON representation and the headers say you're sending XML ... very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating the length correctly, so possibly a syntax error before the ajax request.

```
var data = {
    "Id": 1,
    "Value": 10,
    "UId" : "ab400"
}

var dataLength = JSON.stringify(data).length;

$.ajax({
  url: 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/keDZXXDxK1c/ratings',
  type:"POST",
  data: data,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "Content-Length": dataLength
  },
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use **JSON.stringify()** to get the complete string then apply length attribute to get length.

```
    var data = {
            "Id": 1,
            "Value": 10,
            "UId" : "ab400"
        }

        var Length = JSON.stringify(data).length;
         console.log(Length);//33
         console.log(data.length);//undefined, because here data is object not string.
```

Comment: Will never give you correct length of the data..You can try it yourself..Stringify adds additional / in order to make object as string

Comment: no just log this and count each char : console.log(JSON.stringify(data));// here no / will be there