# Calculate file size of HTML code returned from API

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

The goal: Output the file size of HTML snippet returned from a fetch() call in JavaScript.

**Response from fetch request**

```
{
 content: "<p>Image Long html code block within this property</p>"
}
```

How would I calculate the size of content property, whether in KB or MB? How can I achieve this in JavaScript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate Content-Length in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762778/how-to-calculate-content-length-in-javascript)

Comment: [An answer on "How many bytes in a JavaScript string?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52254083/14956277): `new Blob([response.content]).size`.