# What can cause string length to be incorrectly reported in Node JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

On inspection in the debugger, the value of `html` in the code below ends with `</html>\n` as expected, but as received in browser the last six characters (`/html>`) are missing.

```js
let html = this.code!.asHtml();
response.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Type": "text/html; charset=utf-8",
    "Content-Length": html.length
});
response.end(html);
```

When I comment out the content length header like so

```js
let html = this.code!.asHtml();
response.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Type": "text/html; charset=utf-8",
    //"Content-Length": html.length
});
response.end(html);
```

The delivered page is no longer truncated. WTF?! This implies that html.length is not reporting the correct number of characters. Probably this has something to do with character sets, but I'm not sure how to proceed and would appreciate advice.

Comment: `Probably this has something to do with character sets,` that is likely to be the case.  `html.length is not reporting the correct number of characters.` that's the wrong conclusion,  it returns the number of chars, but `Content-Length` are bytes and not chars. What does `Buffer.byteLength(html, 'utf8')` compared to `html.length` show?

Comment: The `Content-Length` header needs to provide the number of bytes in the response body, not the number of characters.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length#description

Comment: @Bergi yes, that occurred to me after t.niese's comment, and a quick experiment bears it out.

Comment: @t.niese pose that comment as an answer, it constitutes a solution. In particular you told me how to get the number of bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `(new TextEncoder().encode(html)).length` ([mdn: TextEncoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder/TextEncoder), [node: util.TextEncoder](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#class-utiltextencoder)) or `Buffer.byteLength(html, 'utf8')` ([node: Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#static-method-bufferbytelengthstring-encoding)) instead:

`Content-Length` is the number of bytes of the body not the number of chars.

> html.length is not reporting the correct number of characters.

[`.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length#description) is reporting the number of characters (if it is UTF-8) or more precisely UTF-16 code units.

> The length property of a String object contains the length of the string, in UTF-16 code units. length is a read-only data property of string instances. ...

Not relevant for you case but also important to know:

> ... it's possible for the value returned by length to not match the actual number of characters in the string

In UTF-8 or 16 one character may be encoded by more than one byte. So `html.length` can indeed be too small.