# Sending POST with javascript

Tags: php, javascript

**What is wrong with this code? Trying to send data over POST w/ javascript to a PHP page but it isn't sending anything, nothing comes across in the headers $_POST contains nothing.**

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" id="userSub" class="userSub">
<table>
    <tr><td colspan="2">Sign In Here&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Username:</td><td><input name="username" type="text" id="username"  /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input name="pwd" type="text" id="pwd" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" onclick="loginSub()" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2">Need a Username? <a href="signup.html">Sign Up</a></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function loginSub(){
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("rssnav2").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

xmlhttp.open("POST","PHP/login.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send();

}
```

PHP doesn't do anything special right now, just seeing if I can pass the post information to it:

```
<?php
echo "test";
$username=$_POST['username'];
echo $username;
?>
```

It is IS echoing that 'test' line to the correct  so it is communicating w/ the PHP page. Also, I know that I still have the pwd input in "text" type and I know its probably a good idea to hash a password before sending it to the server.

Thanks for your help, everyone!

Comment: getElementById("rssnav2") ??  i dont see any html with such id..

Comment: Sorry Rahul, that is a div in another part of my HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xmlhttp` doesn't actually have any knowledge of the `<form>`, so it won't send any data automatically.

You'll instead have to gather the `<form>`'s data yourself, format it as URL-encoded, and `.send()` it along with the request.

```
function loginSub(){
    var user = document.getElementById('username');
    var pass = document.getElementById('pwd');

    var postData = [
        encodeURIComponent(user.name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(user.value),
        encodeURIComponent(pass.name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(pass.value)
    ].join('&');

    // ...

    xmlhttp.send(postData);
}
```

For more details, you may want to read through MDN's [Using XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest), especially the sections on [Using nothing but *pure* AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Using_nothing_but_pure_AJAX).

It includes a generalized solution for gathering `<form>` data in [A little *vanilla* framework](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#A_little_vanilla_framework), which you could use with:

```
<form method="POST" action="PHP/login.php" onsubmit="AJAXSubmit(this); return false;">
```

---

Side note:

Your `<form>` is likely still submitting as well and may interrupt the Ajax request. You can prevent this by cancelling its `onsubmit` event:

```
<form method="POST" id="userSub" class="userSub" onsubmit="return false">
```

Also, there are more ways to submit a `<form>` than clicking the `type="submit"`. For example, most browsers allow submitting by simply tapping <kbd>Enter</kbd> while typing in a `type="text"` or `type="password"`. And, doing so won't typically imitate a `click` of the `type="submit"`.

So, you'll want to at least consider moving the call out of the `onclick` and into the `onsubmit`:

```
<form method="POST" id="userSub" class="userSub" onsubmit="loginSub(); return false;">
```

Comment: Awesome answer, worked well! Thanks for including those resources!

Answer (score 1):

You are not sending parameters in your `XMLHttpRequest`. Something like:

```
var params = "username=user&password=something";
xmlhttp.open("POST", "PHP/login.php", true);

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("rssnav2").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.send(params);
```

Comment: Be careful with setting `Content-Length` to the `String`'s `length`. JavaScript `String`s are UTF-16 encoded, but will be sent UTF-8 encoded. The lengths will match if the string consists entirely of ASCII characters. But, beyond that, you'll need to get the UTF-8 byte-length for the header. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5515960

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
xmlhttp.send();
```

to

```
xmlhttp.send('username='+document.getElementById('username').value);
```

Of course you will need to put in validation logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
function loginSub()
{
var xmlhttp = false;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    if(typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined')
    {
        try
        {
            return xmlhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
        }

        catch(e)
        {
            return xmlhttp= false;
        }
    }

    else if( window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        try
        {
            return xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            try
            {
                return xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                return xmlhttp = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
var xmlhttp=false;
xmlhttp=createobject();
if(xmlhttp)
{   
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById('rssnav2').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    parameter=username+'='+document.getElementById('usernname').value;
    xmlhttp.open('POST','PHP/login.php',true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlhttp.send(parameter);
}
```

}

this will solve your problem