# How to count the correct length of a string with emojis in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, emoji

I've a little problem.

I'm using NodeJS as backend. Now, an user has a field "biography", where the user can write something about himself.

Suppose that this field has 220 maxlength, and suppose this as input:

```
‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍⚕️‍⚕️‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍
```

As you can see there aren't 220 emojis (there are 37 emojis), but if I do in my nodejs server

```
console.log(bio.length)
```

where bio is the input text, I got 221. How could I "parse" the string input to get the correct length? Is it a problem about unicode?

**SOLVED**

I used this library: https://github.com/orling/grapheme-splitter

I tried that:

```
var Grapheme = require('grapheme-splitter');
var splitter = new Grapheme();
console.log(splitter.splitGraphemes(bio).length);
```

and the length is 37. It works very well!

Comment: https://blog.jonnew.com/posts/poo-dot-length-equals-two - Is a good explaination.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting unicode characters in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25292855/counting-unicode-characters-in-javascript)

Comment: ```Buffer.from(string).length```

Comment: The `Buffer.from(string).length` returns 481

Comment: One thing is to consider what is important: storage allocation in bytes or the number of characters that can be entered. Remember even accented characters can exist in combined and non-combined form. Think three bytes vs two bytes. Also, is text stored at UTF8 or UTF16? This post is a good read: https://blog.jonnew.com/posts/poo-dot-length-equals-two

Comment: I'm using MongoDB as database, so it is in UTF8..

Comment: I've tried grapheme-splitter `new GraphemeSplitter().countGraphemes('‍‍‍‍️‍');` results in `4`. So not entirely reliable.

Comment: you can simply use this approach
[...new Intl.Segmenter().segment('')].length  
And dont need use any library

Answer (score 58, accepted):

1. `str.length` gives the count of UTF-16 units.
2. Unicode-proof way to get string length in codepoints (in characters) is `[...str].length` as iterable protocol splits the string to codepoints.
3. If we need the length in graphemes (grapheme clusters), we have these native ways:

   a. Unicode property escapes in RegExp. See for example: [Unicode-aware version of \w](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-unicode-property-escapes#unicode-aware-version-of-w) or [Matching emoji](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-unicode-property-escapes#matching-emoji).

   b. [Intl.Segmenter](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-intl-segmenter) — coming soon, probably in ES2021. Can be tested with a flag in the last V8 versions (realization was synced with the last spec in V8 86). Unflagged (shipped) in V8 87.

See also:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)
- [What every JavaScript developer should know about Unicode](https://dmitripavlutin.com/what-every-javascript-developer-should-know-about-unicode/)
- [JavaScript has a Unicode problem](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode)
- [Unicode-aware regular expressions in ES2015](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es6-unicode-regex)
- [ES6 Strings (and Unicode, ❤) in Depth](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-strings-and-unicode-in-depth)
- [JavaScript for impatient programmers. Unicode – a brief introduction](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_unicode.html)

Comment: does destructing the example string return 37 though?  130 for me.

Comment: Well, then we need to define in what units the max length should be. We have 221 UTF-16 units, 131 Unicode points (characters) or 37 combined graphemes.

Comment: The question is pretty asking for code that would output 37, rather than 130. `[...str].length` is incorrect for counting emojis as a single unit. You might want to clarify this in your answer so that you don't cause people unnecessary trouble.

Comment: none of these gives correct answer for `‍‍‍`

Comment: @R3m `[...new Intl.Segmenter().segment('‍‍‍')].length` gives `1` (grapheme) if you need `1`.

Comment: @R3m Also, in some cases, this proposal will help: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-unicode-sequence-properties

Comment: your second "unicode proof" does not work with , it returns a length of `2`

Comment: @AntoineWeber That is because there are 2 Unicode characters there: `[...''].map(char => char.codePointAt(0).toString(16))` gives `['1f1ef', '1f1f5']`. You need the third way here: `[...new Intl.Segmenter().segment('')].length` is `1`.

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR there are solutions, but they don’t work in every case. Unicode can feel like a dark art.

There seems to be limitations in various solutions I have seen presented, with the issue going beyond emojis and covering other characters in the Unicode range. Consider é can be stored as é or e + ‘, if using [combing characters](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character). This can even lead to two strings that look the same [not being equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805711/javascript-string-comparison-fails-when-comparing-unicode-characters). Also note, in certain cases a single emoji can be 11 characters when stored and as a result 22 bytes, assuming UTF16.

The way this is handled and how characters are combined, or displayed, can even vary between browsers and operating systems. So, while you may think you cracked it, there is a risk another environment breaks this. Be sure to test where it matters.

Now, there is the front-end vs back-end problem: you solved the character count problem so it works well for human users, now your single emoji blows right past the allocated field size in the database. Less of an issue with databases such as mongo, but can be one with SQL databases, where field allocation was conservative. This means how you solve your problem will depend where the hardest limitation comes in.

Note, that a basic solution does involve converting a string to an array and getting the length, accepting limitations:

```
Array.from(str)
```

This will fall apart when characters are combined and dealing with [astral planes](http://www.opoudjis.net/unicode/unicode_astral.html).

A few high level approaches, that take into account limitations:

- use approaches that solve the front-end issue, as best as possible, and then ensure storage issues are resolved
- be more conservative with the advertised front-end limits, if the database or other storage can’t be adjusted
- limit the character types that can be entered
- clearly indicate limitations of the length calculation

Additionally, given the complexity of the issue it may be worth seeing if there is a popular JS library that already deals with this? I did not find one at the time of writing. Hopefully this is something that would become core to Javascript at some point.

Other pages to read:

- https://blog.jonnew.com/posts/poo-dot-length-equals-two
- https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode
- https://www.contentful.com/blog/2016/12/06/unicode-javascript-and-the-emoji-family/
- https://dmitripavlutin.com/what-every-javascript-developer-should-know-about-unicode/

Answer (score 5):

I answered to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64261876/14413422)

But basically, here it is :

```
''.match(/./gu).length == 1
```

As :

```
''.length == 2
```

More precision in my original post

Comment: Does not work for all cases. For example, `"‍❤️‍‍".match(/./gu).length` outputs `8`

Comment: Yea it's not perfect, but still better than `"‍❤️‍‍".length`

Comment: ''.match(/./gu).length === 2

Answer (score 2):

```
function fancyCount2(str){
  const joiner = "\u{200D}";
  const split = str.split(joiner);
  let count = 0;

  for(const s of split){
    //removing the variation selectors
    const num = Array.from(s.split(/[\ufe00-\ufe0f]/).join("")).length;
    count += num;
  }

  //assuming the joiners are used appropriately
  return count / split.length;
}
```

Comment: It would have been nice to credit the post where you got that from: https://blog.jonnew.com/posts/poo-dot-length-equals-two The post explains how it works and notes that there are cases where it doesn't work.

Comment: I swear I didn't read that article before, I just thought of using regex myself, but still a must read article

Answer (score 1):

With [a regex that can parse emojis](https://github.com/sweaver2112/Regex-combined-emojis), this can be done easily and without the use of external libraries.  Please see the code snippets for examples. ‍♀️

Note that **grapheme-splitter** as suggested in the question will overcount and split apart compound emojis that contain other emojis, such as this one: ‍‍.  This is reported as three distinct "graphemes",  ‍ and ‍ and

Here we are using the 'compact', literal version so it'll fit, but there's a safe, long version that uses Unicode escapes as well.

For more info on the regex see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64085060/244811).

```js
/*the pattern (compact version)*/
var emojiPattern = String.raw`(?:‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍||||‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍‍‍|‍‍‍|‍‍‍|‍‍‍|‍‍‍|‍‍‍|‍‍‍|‍‍‍|‍‍‍|‍‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|️‍️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍⚕️|‍⚕️|‍⚕️|‍⚕️|‍⚕️|‍⚕️|‍⚕️|‍⚕️|‍⚕️|‍⚕️|‍⚕️|‍⚕️|‍⚕️|‍⚕️|‍⚕️|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍⚖️|‍⚖️|‍⚖️|‍⚖️|‍⚖️|‍⚖️|‍⚖️|‍⚖️|‍⚖️|‍⚖️|‍⚖️|‍⚖️|‍⚖️|‍⚖️|‍⚖️|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍✈️|‍✈️|‍✈️|‍✈️|‍✈️|‍✈️|‍✈️|‍✈️|‍✈️|‍✈️|‍✈️|‍✈️|‍✈️|‍✈️|‍✈️|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍️|️‍♂️|️‍♀️|️‍♂️|️‍♀️|️‍♂️|️‍♀️|️‍|️‍⚧️|⛹‍♂️|⛹‍♂️|⛹‍♂️|⛹‍♂️|⛹‍♂️|⛹‍♀️|⛹‍♀️|⛹‍♀️|⛹‍♀️|⛹‍♀️|‍|‍|❤️‍|❤️‍|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍⚕️|‍⚕️|‍⚕️|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍⚖️|‍⚖️|‍⚖️|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍✈️|‍✈️|‍✈️|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|⛹️‍♂️|⛹️‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍❄️|‍☠️|‍⬛|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||#️⃣|0️⃣|1️⃣|2️⃣|3️⃣|4️⃣|5️⃣|6️⃣|7️⃣|8️⃣|9️⃣|✋|✋|✋|✋|✋|✌|✌|✌|✌|✌|☝|☝|☝|☝|☝|✊|✊|✊|✊|✊|✍|✍|✍|✍|✍|⛹|⛹|⛹|⛹|⛹||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||☺|☹|☠|❣|❤|✋|✌|☝|✊|✍|⛷|⛹|☘|☕|⛰|⛪|⛩|⛲|⛺|♨|⛽|⚓|⛵|⛴|✈|⌛|⏳|⌚|⏰|⏱|⏲|☀|⭐|☁|⛅|⛈|☂|☔|⛱|⚡|❄|☃|⛄|☄|✨|⚽|⚾|⛳|⛸|♠|♥|♦|♣|♟|⛑|☎|⌨|✉|✏|✒|✂|⛏|⚒|⚔|⚙|⚖|⛓|⚗|⚰|⚱|♿|⚠|⛔|☢|☣|⬆|↗|➡|↘|⬇|↙|⬅|↖|↕|↔|↩|↪|⤴|⤵|⚛|✡|☸|☯|✝|☦|☪|☮|♈|♉|♊|♋|♌|♍|♎|♏|♐|♑|♒|♓|⛎|▶|⏩|⏭|⏯|◀|⏪|⏮|⏫|⏬|⏸|⏹|⏺|⏏|♀|♂|⚧|✖|➕|➖|➗|♾|‼|⁉|❓|❔|❕|❗|〰|⚕|♻|⚜|⭕|✅|☑|✔|❌|❎|➰|➿|〽|✳|✴|❇|©|®|™|ℹ|Ⓜ|㊗|㊙|⚫|⚪|⬛|⬜|◼|◻|◾|◽|▪|▫)`

/*compile the pattern string into a regex*/
let emoRegex = new RegExp(emojiPattern, "g");

/*count of emojis*/
let emoCount = [..."‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍⚕️‍⚕️‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍".matchAll(emoRegex)].length

console.log(emoCount) //37

/*modifying the pattern to count other characters too*/
let generalCounter = new RegExp(emojiPattern+"|.", "g") //emoji or regular character
let allCount = [..."$%^ other stuff equalling 28‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️‍⚕️‍⚕️‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍".matchAll(generalCounter)].length

console.log(allCount) //28+37 = 65
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, I had a similar problem where I wanted to count the length of an emoji at the end of a string.

This is the solution I came up with:

```js
var emoji = new RegExp('(\\p{Extended_Pictographic})((\u200D\\p{Extended_Pictographic})*)$', 'u');

var testStrings = ['‍‍', '', ''];

for(var string = 0; string < testStrings.length; string++){

  var match = testStrings[string].match(emoji);
  var chars = match == null ? 0 : match[0].length;
  
  console.log(testStrings[string] + ': ' + chars);
  
}
```

**Explanation:** `\\p{Extended_Pictographic}` matches an emoji like , consisting of two characters. Emojis like ‍‍ consists of 4 emojis (, , ,) combined by [a zero width joiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_joiner) (`\u200D`).

The regex matches any emoji *at the end* (`$`). If there is a match the length is counted. I am sure it could be adopted for your use-case by matching all emojis in a given string and then subtracting the surplus. It's not a complete implementation for your particular question but I hope this gets you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the below example, this is to do with unicode encoding,

There's some great resources such as the one I took this example from.

https://blog.jonnew.com/posts/poo-dot-length-equals-two

```js
console.log("‍❤️‍‍".length === 11);
```

Comment: I readed that and tested the fancycount function too, it didn't worked for me..I readed also about fancycount2 version.

Answer (score 0):

### use lodash toArray method

```
console.log(_.toArray("‍‍").length); // 1
console.log(_.toArray("‍‍‍♂️‍‍").length); // 3
```

Check [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/js-emoji-length-lodash-6qtibc?file=/src/index.js) for Codesandbox

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely not as good as [grapheme-splitter](https://github.com/orling/grapheme-splitter) (see the answer), but I made a RegExp that works for most combining characters and emojis

```js
/**
 * ## RegExp matching each (combined) unicode symbol/character/emoji consecutively
 * | flag        | description                                                    |
 * |:----------- |:-------------------------------------------------------------- |
 * | G (global)  | matches all possible characters                                |
 * | U (unicode) | match with full unicode                                        |
 * | Y (sticky)  | start matching at beginning of string or end of previous match |
 * @type {RegExp}
 * @example Array.from("ü^‍‍‍G".matchAll(unicodeRegExp),v=>v[0]); //=> [ "ü", "", "", "^", "‍‍‍", "G" ]
 */
const unicodeRegExp=/(?:\p{Extended_Pictographic}[\p{Emoji_Modifier}\p{M}]*(?:\p{Join_Control}\p{Extended_Pictographic}[\p{Emoji_Modifier}\p{M}]*)*|\s|.)\p{M}*/guy;
```

(*see [this RegExp on regex101](https://regex101.com/library/1sHYup) for more info on that (click "open regex in editor")*)

and a generator function

```js
/**
 * ## creates an iterator for each (combined) unicode symbol in the string
 * JS generator function yielding each character (with indices)
 * @param {string} str - a string
 * @param {boolean} [crlf] - if `true` combines `CR` and `LF` into one character `CRLF` (if present in this constellation) - default `false`
 * @generator
 * @yields {[string,number,number]} `[combined unicode symbol, string index, symbol index]`
 * @throws {TypeError} if {@linkcode str} is not a string or {@linkcode crlf} is not a boolean
 * @example Array.from(unicodeIterator("ü^‍‍‍G"),v=>v[0]); //=> [ "ü", "", "", "^", "‍‍‍", "G" ]
 */
function*unicodeIterator(str,crlf){
    "use strict";
    if(typeof str!=="string")throw new TypeError("[unicodeIterator] str is not a string");
    if(crlf==null)crlf=false;
    else if(typeof crlf!=="boolean")throw new TypeError("[unicodeIterator] crlf is not a boolean");
    if(str==="")return;
    /**
     * ## get UTF 16 unicode symbol (code point) at {@linkcode index} in {@linkcode string}
     * @param {string} string - a string
     * @param {number} index - zero-based index
     * @returns {string} the UTF 16 character at {@linkcode index} (might have length 2, or an empty string if there's nothing to get the code point from)
     */
    const utf16At=(string,index)=>{
        "use strict";
        const codePoint=string.codePointAt(index);
        if(codePoint===undefined)return"";
        return String.fromCodePoint(codePoint);
    }
    let l=0;
    for(let i=0;i<str.length;){
        let symbol="";
        do{
            const char=utf16At(str,i+symbol.length);
            symbol+=char;
            if(crlf&&char==="\r"&&str[i+1]==="\n")symbol+="\n";
            let zalgo=utf16At(str,i+symbol.length);
            while(/^[\p{Emoji_Modifier}\p{M}]$/u.test(zalgo)){
                symbol+=zalgo;
                zalgo=utf16At(str,i+symbol.length);
            }
            const joiner=utf16At(str,i+symbol.length);
            if(/^\p{Join_Control}$/u.test(joiner))symbol+=joiner;
            else break;
        }while(true);
        yield[symbol,i+=symbol.length,l++];
    }
}
```

I tested both with

f☺⣿fg‍‍‍ll️‍o͂ȩl^^\n‍❤️‍‍अनुच्छेद\rs뎌쉐a\n\r\ns‍fggZ͑ͫ̓ͪ̂ͫ̽͏̴̙̤̞͉͚̯̞̠͍A̴̵̜̰͔ͫ͗͢L̠ͨͧͩ͘G̴̻͈͍͔̹̑͗̎̅͛́Ǫ̵̹̻̝̳͂̌̌͘!͖̬̰̙̗̿̋ͥͥ̂ͣ̐́́͜͞

(*JS string length is 161, and iterating over the code points gets it to 142*)

and they both got

49 [ 'f', '', '☺', '⣿', '', 'f', '', 'g', '‍‍‍', 'l', 'l', '️‍', 'o͂', 'ȩ', 'l', '^', '^', '', '\n', '‍❤️‍‍', 'अ', 'नु', 'च्', 'छे', 'द', '\r', 's', '', 'ᄃ', 'ᅧ', 'ᄉ', 'ᅰ', '', 'a', '\n', '\r', '\n', 's', '‍', 'f', '', 'g', 'g', 'Z͑ͫ̓ͪ̂ͫ̽͏̴̙̤̞͉͚̯̞̠͍', 'A̴̵̜̰͔ͫ͗͢', 'L̠ͨͧͩ͘', 'G̴̻͈͍͔̹̑͗̎̅͛́', 'Ǫ̵̹̻̝̳͂̌̌͘', '!͖̬̰̙̗̿̋ͥͥ̂ͣ̐́́͜͞' ]

which is good enough in my eyes, grapheme-splitter gets you

46 [ 'f', '', '☺', '⣿', '', 'f', '', 'g', '‍‍‍', 'l', 'l', '️‍', 'o͂', 'ȩ', 'l', '^', '^', '', '\n', '‍❤️‍‍', 'अ', 'नु', 'च्', 'छे', 'द', '\r', 's', '', '뎌', '쉐', '', 'a', '\n', '\r\n', 's', '‍', 'f', '', 'g', 'g', 'Z͑ͫ̓ͪ̂ͫ̽͏̴̙̤̞͉͚̯̞̠͍', 'A̴̵̜̰͔ͫ͗͢', 'L̠ͨͧͩ͘', 'G̴̻͈͍͔̹̑͗̎̅͛́', 'Ǫ̵̹̻̝̳͂̌̌͘', '!͖̬̰̙̗̿̋ͥͥ̂ͣ̐́́͜͞' ]

which combines the `CR` and `LF` (*can be easily added. the generator function already has that as an option*) and also splits the `뎌쉐` differently (correctly after [`Default Grapheme Cluster Boundary` of `UAX #29`](https://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Default_Grapheme_Cluster_Table) of which grapheme-splitter is based on)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using the runes package to accomplish correct multi-byte string conversions cause else you will get more issues if using reducers and more to reverse strings for example.

Take a look at this great small package: [runes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/runes)

Comment: Look very promising however the latest update of this package was 4 years ago (2 Oct 2017)

Comment: Yeah I know it's been 4 year that a new version has been released but it still works as supposed and no peer dependency depreciation so for now I still use it for multi-byte string conversions instead of loading it into a Buffer with the correct encoding.

Comment: Fair enough. Instead of using additional package (runes or emoji-regex) I used lodash (as it's already included in my project). I came to this solution text to this answer on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64138318/1732989)

Comment: Great and indeed you can use lodash also if it's already included and you also use other lodash methods because else I think that lodash is overkill and with many packages I don't want to have too much bloatware. But lodash is amazing. I also used momentjs for datetime manipulation but for many smaller projects that don't really need localization etc....I simply use the native ES6+ methods and I did that with a lot of packages that were actually just easy rather than needed and yes performance increased with 20% so that is significant.