# Does PHP have equivalent string length function than JavaScript's string length function? ("‍♂️".length === 7, int(5), int(17))

Tags: javascript, php

Please see this example:

## In JavaScript

```js
console.log('‍♂️'.length) // 7
```

## In PHP

```php
<?php

var_dump(strlen("‍♂️")); // int(17)
var_dump(mb_strlen("‍♂️")); // int(5)
```

How can I make sure my backend count my string length exactly as my frontend?

Comment: Very related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54369605/476

Comment: See @ÁlvaroGonzález answer to the duplicate, it gives a better explanation than the accpeted answer.