# Content-length body with mixed latin and chinese characters

Tags: javascript, chinese-locale, content-length

I am defining the Content-Length of an HTTP request but because sometimes it might contain chinese characters when it gets to the response side of things, it gets truncated.

I have been trying to get the right way to set the content-length of a mixed Chinese/Latin String but with no luck. it keeps getting truncated.

```
headers["Content-Length"] = data.length;   //fails
```

```
{ \"query\": \"周杰伦\", \"type\": \"artist\"} //gets truncated
```

```
{ \"query\": \"gennaro\", \"type\": \"artist\"} //successful request
```

Can anyone suggest how to calculate the second string length for the content-length header properly?

NOTE: the body is stringified from JSON before it is sent over.

Thanks

Comment: [content length double byte](https://www.google.com/search?q=content-length+double+byte+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @mplungjan what do you mean by that?

Comment: Click it for similar questions and their answers

Comment: And I assume you did `headers["Content-Length"] = data.length; ` AFTER the json_encode

Comment: While I'm not sure what @connexo expects you to do with C# code, your question leaves a bit too much for imagination. How are you sending that data? Are you really expected to set the header yourself? Please provide relevant code portions, preferably an [mre].

Comment: Unfortunately I picked the wrong duplicate. Here's the actual one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54369513/how-to-count-the-correct-length-of-a-string-with-emojis-in-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count the correct length of a string with emojis in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54369513/how-to-count-the-correct-length-of-a-string-with-emojis-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

The fix this issue , I used TextEncoder which allow me to encode it to utf8 and then count it in the correct way.

```
let bodyLength = (new TextEncoder().encode(dataBody)).length;
```