# jquery countdown characters not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code to countdown characters. It work fine in Firefox, Chrome but it not work in IE . Can you help me solve it and explain the reason.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CountDown Character</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <textarea name="message1" id="message1" cols="30" rows="10" data-limit="10"></textarea>
        <br>
        <span name="remLen1" id="remLen1">10</span>
    </form>
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#message1').on("keyup keydown",
            function () {
                var limit = $(this).data("limit");
                var remainingChars = limit - $(this).val().length;
                console.log(remainingChars);
                if (remainingChars <= 0) {
                    $('#message1').val($('#message1').val().substring(0,limit));
                }
                $("#remLen1").html(remainingChars<=0?0:remainingChars);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.
Ex: I'm using countdown japanese characters and alpha character.

Comment: `<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">` ? Please come back to modern age

Comment: Thanks. I will repair it.

Comment: I have been removed it and it was worked fine. But now i have a problem. When i press the 11th character (japanese character) it replace old string by new character and coutdown 9.

Comment: Japanese characters (and many other non-ASCII) uses multi-byte to represent a character. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515869/string-length-in-bytes-in-javascript)

Comment: I use alert() show the string after substring, It return value true, but it display in textarea not true. It display new character. Why this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and found that `console.log(remainingChars);` is causing problem as it gives error : console is undefined. Remove this line and your code will work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#message1').on("keyup keydown",
    function () {
        var limit = $(this).data("limit");
        var remainingChars = limit - $(this).val().length;
        /*console.log(remainingChars);*/
        if (remainingChars <= 0) {
            $('#message1').val($('#message1').val().substring(0,limit));
        }
        $("#remLen1").html(remainingChars<=0?0:remainingChars);
    });
});
```

And if you still want to use `console`, then see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326650/console-is-undefined-error-for-internet-explorer) for solution.

Comment: Thanks you. It was worked. But when i press the character 11th (using japanese character) it replace the old string by new character and countdown 9.

Comment: try with `keyup` event only

Comment: It still error. Can you try press the japanese characters.

Comment: try with `alert($(this).val().length)` and see what it returns.

Comment: it return true, but it display in textarea not true. It display new character. One more things, i run this code in another computer it display true. Can you explain reason why this?