# Amount of transferred bytes per web request

Tags: javascript, http, firefox, xmlhttprequest

When you do a XMLHttpRequest, the data is often compressed. Looking at [the `Content-Length` header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773396/whats-the-content-length-field-in-http-header)

```
xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Length");
```

gives you the number of octets in the response body, to which you could add an approximation of the header by sizing the response headers.

But: **How do you find the number of (compressed) bytes actually transferred?** (in Firefox, if this is only possible in a browser-specific way.)

In the screenshot below, you see a difference for several files:
[image: different sizes transferred than received]

The following should all be equal to this

- the number of bytes read from the socket
- the file size in the squid log
- the number of application-layer octets sent over the network in response to the request

Comment: Hm, that's not the number of octets in the response but the number of octets in the *response body*. Important difference. I take it you want the number of octets over the entire message?

Comment: @DaSourcerer: exactly. Thank you.

Comment: @DaSourcerer: and if it is compressed, the number of compressed octets

Comment: True. But that would still be the same as the number of octets in the response body. HTTP messages can be surprisingly agnostic towards their payload: The compression is a property of the content, not the message itself. At least as far as the `Content-Encoding` header is concerned.

Comment: @DaSourcerer: That information is again useful (and might explain why the transferred size is *bigger* than the content size for several items in the picture). To clarify: the number of application-layer octets sent over the network in response to the request.

Comment: There could indeed be another reason: If a server is configured to compress images as well, they could actually *increase* in size through the compression. The established algorithms for HTTP transport tend to not work that well on binary data ;)

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: the [performance api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceResourceTiming) seems to provide this: Call as

```
performance.getEntries()[0]
```

and see the [`encodedBodySize`](https://w3c.github.io/resource-timing/#dom-performanceresourcetiming-encodedbodysize) (see [also at MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceResourceTiming).

---

The screenshot above shows the [Network Monitor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor). [Its code](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/devtools/client/netmonitor) seems to use the [`network-monitor.js`](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/devtools/shared/webconsole/network-monitor.js) file which

> implements the nsIStreamListener and nsIRequestObserver interfaces. This is used within the NetworkMonitor feature to get the response body of the request.

The relevant code seems to be

> ```
>   onProgress: function(request, context, progress, progressMax) {
>     this.transferredSize = progress;
>     // Need to forward as well to keep things like Download Manager's progress
>     // bar working properly.
>     this._forwardNotification(Ci.nsIProgressEventSink, "onProgress", arguments);
>   },
> ```

with

> ```
>   _onComplete: function NRL__onComplete(aData)
>   {
>     let response = {
>       mimeType: "",
>       text: aData || "",
>     };
>
>     response.size = response.text.length;
>     response.transferredSize = this.transferredSize;
> ```

The `progress` event is part of neither interface. It may be from [xhr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress), but where it came from is as of yet unclear.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the response is text (as opposed to binary blobs), you have some good starting points here, on SO :
[Measure string length in bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515869/string-length-in-bytes-in-javascript)

Comment: It seems my question was not clear enough. It is about the number of bytes *as sent*, including compression. Or did you mean that the text could be reconstituted, then recompressed? (the link talks about something similar to this with encoding)