# How to get the real length of Japanese string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string-length, double-byte

How can I get the real length of Japanese string?
For example, the `length()` function would return the bytes length, not the actual length.

```
s = "";

alert(s.length);    // '2'
```

Is there any way to get the real length which is in this case 1?

Comment: s.split("").length maybe...

Comment: @Mr.7: or [String length in bytes in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515869/string-length-in-bytes-in-javascript) ?

Comment: @Jonasw even `s.split("").length` also giving `2` only

Comment: @Mr.7 That question wants the number of bytes in a specified encoding. What is wanted here is the number of unicode characters.