# javascript have function like strlen php?

Tags: javascript

I use this javascript code

```
<input id="text" value="漢字">
var text_val = document.getElementById("text").value.length;  // result will be 2 //
```

for as same as php code

```
$text_val = mb_strlen('漢字', 'utf-8'); // result will be 2 //
```

And then i want to know what javascript as same as this php code ?

```
$text_val = strlen("漢字");  // result will be 6 //
```

Comment: PHP by default only deals with ASCII strings so its reading each byte.

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515869/string-length-in-bytes-in-javascript

Comment: Possibly a better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515869/string-length-in-bytes-in-javascript

Comment: @Troyer — jinx!

Comment: Try unescape(encodeURIComponent("漢字")).length (from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515869/string-length-in-bytes-in-javascript).