# String length validation based on bytes and not length

Tags: unicode

I have been asked by a Japanese person to change the string length validation of a form.

Currently, does normal string length validation (what counts is the number of characters regardless of what those characters are).

What I've been asked to do is to validate string length based on bytes - in other words, `four 1-byte characters` and one `2-byte characters` would account for a length of `6-byte` total length even though there's `5` characters.

And what I need to know is:

1) Are there only 1 and 2 byte characters? ([This question talks about 3 and 4 byte characters)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6872/are-the-4-byte-utf-8-kanji-rare-enough-that-i-can-ignore-them)

2) What are the range of all characters that I should count as 1 byte or 2 bytes?
I am sure the person who asked me for this can give a few examples but I really must have all cases covered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a UTF-8 encode web-based input form, you should able to distinguish ASCII and other language based on its 1st-byte value- range. Please see example Javascript code in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515869/string-length-in-bytes-in-javascript) and [Wikipedia's explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) . Other Unicode encodings have similar rule  but you have to look further in details