# Count String count in JavaScript for Non- Ascii characters

Tags: javascript, string

I want to add client side validation for counting characters. That field limit is 300 in database. At server side validation, I get proper string length but while saving form as draft, server side validation is bypassed.

So i get exception. Can anyone help to check character length for Latin characters like

```
£, §, £, Ä
```

For Example:

```
String s= "wa£erw£";

System.out.println("SiZE "+s.length());

System.out.println("UTF - SiZE "+s.getBytes(java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length );
```

Output:

```
SiZE 7
UTF - SiZE 9
```

I need Count 9 using JavaScript

Comment: We can't debug code that you haven't shown us

Comment: @JamesThorpe it is character count

Comment: In Database I am storing as UTF-8 String

Answer (score 1):

Lets clear some things - the string `"wa£erw£"`:

- contains 7 characters
- has 9 bytes in UTF-8, be cause of the 2 multi-byte chars in it - these 2 chars will be 2 bytes each and total is 9 bytes.

In JavaScript `.length()` returns the number of characters, so the first result is right. Reference: [JavaScript String length Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_string.asp)

`s.getBytes(java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length` - this will first convert the string to byte array, and then returns the length of this byte array. As per above the byte array will be 9 bytes. So second is also correct.

If you want to get the number of bytes in JS, it is not so easy. You can find some sort of solution in this discussion: [String length in bytes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515869/string-length-in-bytes-in-javascript)

The better approach is to store your string data correctly in your database with same encoding for the whole app (like using UTF-8 in DB for example). Then you will get rid of all overhead of re-encoding texts, validation issues like this and etc. You can also have bad encoding issues if your DB columns differs you remaining app.