# How does office.js 2mb requirement measured?

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins

I want to save different sizes of custom settings data into the excel settings.
But when the custom setting is too big, saveAsync does not save, which is expected - There is a 2mb limit per add-in.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.settings?view=word-js-preview

This is my current code:

```
const bigJsonString = "Very big string";
const jsonObject = JSON.parse(stringValue);
Office.context.document.settings.set('mydata', jsonObject);
Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync((result)=>{
    ...
});
```

I know that *saveAsync* will call the callback method with the result. But somehow it works for Office 365 but not for the Excel Desktop.

I want to measure the *jsonObject* or *bigJsonString* size and if it is more than 2mb stop the *set* and *saveAsync* calls

Something like this:

```
const bigJsonString = "Very big string";
const jsonObject = JSON.parse(stringValue);
if(GetSize(jsonObject) > 2){
    // acknowledge user that add-in can't save customsetting.
} else {
    Office.context.document.settings.set('mydata', jsonObject);
    Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync((result)=>{
    ...
}
});
```

How Office-JS measure the size of the settings object? (I want to mimic)

**Update (side note):**

Based on the below link, it looks like Microsoft removed this 2mb restriction.

[What is the office setting limitation for Excel Add in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62525186/what-is-the-office-setting-limitation-for-excel-add-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to measure the size of the setting using JavaScript.

```
const isWritableSetting = (object) => {
   // .size will return your object size in bytes
   const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(object)], { type: 'application/json' })
   return blob.size < 2 /* Megabytes */ * 1000 /* Kilobytes */* 1000;
};
```

I've tweaked the `1024` to `1000` to be a bit safer; you could validate it to see if it's eligible for `1024 * 1024`.

In your code then, all you need to do is:

```
if (isWritableSetting(object)) ...
```

A good reference for sizing up objects in JS here: [String length in bytes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515869/string-length-in-bytes-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will test this and let you know the result.

Comment: It almost worked but we need to convert object like this:
const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(object)], { type: 'application/json' }). Can you update the answer? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

Comment: Updated the answer!