# Google Analytics - send object to event label through GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer, custom-events

I've configured a custom event on Google Tag Manager to send data about my product to Google Analytics using "datalayer", but when I send hit the event it's label is shown as [object Object] into analytics reports.

How do I get all properties of the product there?

Example of data that I'm pushing:

```js
{
  'event': 'test',
  'action': 'add',
  'product': {
     'id': 32,
     'name': 'Product 1',
     'price': 99.99
  }
}
```

Example of how it's shown on Alanytics reports:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can as eventlabel not send an object in a label because label is type string. Lets make a test

```
var myProducts = {productid:1,productname:"name"}; //your object in datLayer
myProducts.toString(); //which probably analytics does

Output will be  [object Object]
```

Thats means to have to create a string from this object

you can make the object to string like '{productid:1,productname:"name"}'
output in analytics will probably be   {productid:1,productname:"name"}

you can change the form and write it as string  "productid = 1, productname  = name"  //34 byte
than it will displayed as  productid = 1, productname  = name

Max Length for Event Label = 500 Bytes
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#eventAction

you can check stackoverflow how to check the bytes in javascript from string [String length in bytes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515869/string-length-in-bytes-in-javascript)

**Recommended**
Annother thing google has enhanced ecommerce
https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce