# what is the c# equivalent to javascript's unescape()?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

I am trying to analyse some `JavaScript`, and one line is

```
var x = unescape("%u4141%u4141 ......");
```

with lots of characters in form `%uxxxx`.

I want to rewrite the `JavaScript` in `c#` but can't figure out the proper function to decode a string of characters like this.  I've tried

```
HttpUtility.HTMLDecode("%u4141%u4141");
```

but this did not change these characters at all.

How can I accomplish this in c#?

Comment: You are mixing up two different escaping/unescaping methods: one is for entities inside a HTML file, the other is for URLs, i.e. addresses.

Answer (score 14):

You can use [UrlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode.aspx):

```
string decoded = HttpUtility.UrlDecode("%u4141%u4141");
```

`decoded` would then contain `"䅁䅁"`.

As other have pointed out, changing the `%` to `\` would work, but `UrlDecode` is the preferred method, since that ensures that other escaped symbols are translated correctly as well.

Answer (score 4):

You need [`HttpUtility.UrlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode.aspx). You shouldn't really be using `escape/unescape` in most cases nowadays, you should be using things like `encodeURI/decodeURI/encodeURIComponent`.

[When are you supposed to use escape instead of encodeURI / encodeURIComponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619323/decodeuricomponent-vs-unescape-what-is-wrong-with-unescape) covers the issue of why `escape/unescape` are a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can call bellow method to achieve the same effect as Javascript escape/unescape method

```
Microsoft.JScript.GlobalObject.unescape();

Microsoft.JScript.GlobalObject.escape();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the % signs to backslashes and you have a C# string literal. C# treats \uxxxx as an escape sequence, with xxxx being 4 digits.

Comment: Note: this only applies if the string is a hardcoded literal in the ops source code. Maybe he wants to decode some strings that are input into the program. Then ``HttpUtility.UrlDecode`` is the way to go...

Answer (score 0):

In basic string usage you can initiate string variable in Unicode:
var someLine="\u4141";
If it is possible - replace all "%u" with "\u".

Comment: Note: this only applies if the string is a hardcoded literal in the ops source code. Maybe he wants to decode some strings that are input into the program. Then ``HttpUtility.UrlDecode`` is the way to go...

Answer (score 0):

edit the web.config the following parameter:

`< globalization requestEncoding="iso-8859-15" responseEncoding="utf-8" >responseHeaderEncoding="utf-8"` in `< system.web >`