# Replace ASCII characters with their equivalent

Tags: c#, javascript, cookies

I am setting a value in the cookie using JavaScript and getting the contents of the cookie in the code behind.

But the problem is if I am storing the string with some special characters or whitespace characters, when I am retrieving the contents of the cookie the special symbols are getting converted into ASCII equivalent.

For example, if I want to store `Adam - (SET)` in cookie , its getting converted into `Adam%20-%20%28SET%29` and getting stored and when I am retrieving it I get the same `Adam%20-%20%28SET%29`. But I wan tot get this `Adam - (SET)` in the code behind.

How I get this. Please help.

Comment: You want to do the retrieving in c# ?

Comment: Can you clarify whether you need to decode that in JS or C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## In `C#`

Use:

```
String decoded = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(EncodedString);
```

*[HttpUtility.UrlDecode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode.aspx) is the underlying function used by most of the other alternatives you can use in the .NET Framwework (see below).*

*You may want to specify an encoding, if necessary.*

Or:

```
String decoded = Uri.UnescapeDataString(s);
```

*See [Uri.UnescapeDataString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.unescapedatastring.aspx)'s documentation for some caveats.*

## In `JavaScript`

```
var decoded = decodeURIComponent(s);
```

*Before jumping on using `unescape` as recommended in other questions, read [decodeURIComponent vs unescape, what is wrong with unescape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619323/decodeuricomponent-vs-unescape-what-is-wrong-with-unescape) . You may also want to read [What is the difference between decodeURIComponent and decodeURI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747641/what-is-the-difference-between-decodeuricomponent-and-decodeuri) .*

Comment: @Bibhu: You're welcome, glad it helps. If you are satisfied with one of the answers, please use the tick symbol under the vote counter to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `unescape` function in JS to do that.

```
var str = unescape('Adam%20-%20%28SET%29');
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `HttpUtility.UrlDecode()` (in the System.Web namespace, I think)

Answer (score 1):

In javasrcipt you can use the built-in [decodeURIComponent](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1.3.2), but I suspect that the string encoding is happening when the value is sent to server so the C# answers are what you want.