# Matching escaped spaces using JavaScript indexOf

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
var matchArray = [];
var passedUrl = '/' + url;
var tabLink;

$('.uiAjaxTabs li a').each(function () {
    if (passedUrl.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) == 0) {
        boverlap_penalty = passedUrl.replace($(this).attr('href'), '').length;
        matchArray.push({ 'score': boverlap_penalty, 'dom_obj': this });
    }
});

if (matchArray.length) {
    tabLink = matchArray.sort(function (a, b) {
        return (a.score < b.score) ? -1 : 1
    }).shift().dom_obj;
}

$(tabLink).parents('li').addClass('loading');
```

Which takes a passedUrl and then matches it up with a set of links to see which most closely matches the url, and then adds a class of loading to it.

This works fine EXCEPT if the link has a space in it e.g. `domain.com/People?Name=John Doe` because the browser sees it as `domain.com/People?Name=John%20Doe` and therefore doesn't match it correctly when the passedUrl has the escaped spaces and the link does not.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: URLs cannot have spaces.

Comment: Please provide a testcase with some values for `$(this).attr('href')`, the `url` you're using, and the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any ideas on how to fix this?

Use

```
var passedUrl = decodeURI('/' + url);
```

See [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI).

Answer (score 0):

Try JavaScript's `unescape` function, it seem to decode URL-encoded strings.

Comment: Check [decodeURIComponent vs unescape, what is wrong with unescape?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/619323/1048572)